# images loaded onto texture appear completely white

Tags: unity, textures, graphics, image

I am applying a texture to a primitive plane using ARKit and Unity like so,

```
IEnumerator loadSpriteImageFromUrl( string URL, ARPlaneAnchor anchor ){
    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download image on progress" + www.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        GameObject clone = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
        clone.transform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (anchor.transform);
        clone.transform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (anchor.transform);
        clone.transform.localScale = new Vector3(anchor.extent.x * 0.1f ,anchor.extent.y * 0.1f ,anchor.extent.z * 0.1f );
        clone.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(anchor.center.x,anchor.center.y,-anchor.center.z);
        Texture2D texture =new Texture2D(128,128,TextureFormat.RGBA32,false);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
        MeshRenderer m = clone.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        m.material.mainTexture = texture;
    }
```

But the image applied as texture  is completely white with no colors. Can someone please point my mistake. I checked the lighting, there are no issues.

Comment: I never used WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture before, but [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html) says you should use a Texture2d With `TextureFormat.DXT1` or `TextureFormat.RGB24` for Jpeg and `TextureFormat.DXT5` or `TextureFormat.ARGB32` for PNG. You are using `RGBA32` which is recommended for neither. Could that be your mistake?